# Is it possible for __new__ to modify the arguments that __init__ sees?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a class whose `__init__` argument has signature `(self, *args, foo=42, **kwargs)`

Is it possible for the class's `__new__` method to modify the value of the `foo` keyword argument that the `__init__` method eventually sees?

I thought that something like this would do it:

```
import sys
class Wibble(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, foo=42, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.pop('use_floats_only', False):
            print('Warning: using floats only!', file=sys.stderr)
            return cls.__new__(cls, *args, foo=float(foo), **kwargs)
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, *args, foo=42, **kwargs):
        self.foo = foo
```

but:

```
>>> print(type(Wibble(use_floats_only=True).foo))
Warning: using floats only!
<class 'int'>
```

In other words, even though `__new__`'s `if` block got executed, the `__init__` method for the returned instance still got the default value for the `foo` keyword argument.

This leads me to suspect that, no matter what `__new__` may do, it cannot affect the value of `foo` that `__init__` sees.  Is this suspicion correct?

The only purpose of this question is to gain a better understanding of the Python object model.

Comment: [_"If `__new__()` is invoked during object construction and it returns an instance of cls, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where self is the new instance and **the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to the object constructor**"_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) (emphasis mine).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge an existing explicit parameter will never show up on kwargs.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a metaclass and override its `__call__` method:

```
from typing import Any

class Wibble(type):
  def __call__(self, *args, foo=42, **kwds: Any) -> Any:
    kwds['random_float'] = int(kwds['random_float'])
    kwds['injected'] = 'injected'
    return super().__call__(*args, foo=float(foo), **kwds)
    

class Wibble(metaclass=Wibble):
    def __init__(self, foo=42, **kwargs):
        self.foo = foo
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


w = Wibble(use_floats_only=True, random_float=42.2)
print(type(w.foo))
print(type(w.random_float))
print(w.injected)
```

##### Prints

```
<class 'float'>
<class 'int'>
injected
```